# how to subscribe when a plone site is initially loaded on startup

Tags: plone

I'm wanting to make some registrations programatically that depend on data stored in plone.app.registry. Specifically I want to add menuItems to the display menu of an object, which is normally done via zcml.

What is "standard" approach to such a "plone loaded" event?

Approaches I've considered are:

- Use a pre traversal hook on the site root, make the registrations and then set some kind marker to prevent the re-registering
- Listen for a zope startup event (like zope.processlifetime.IProcessStarting) and then find all Plone sites in the ZODB and perform the registrations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use an event handler to hook into site traversal, with a toggle:

```
_menuItemsRegistered = set()

def beforeSiteTraverse(site, event, _handled=set()):
    if site.getPhysicalPath() not in _handled:
        registerMenuItems(site)
        __handled.add(site.getPhysicalPath())
```

Now `registerMenuItems` will be executed only once for each Plone site, and is very cheap to execute.

You could reduce this (much further) if you only had to deal with one Plone site per instance; simply unsubscribe your handler after firing the first time.

This works better than handling a `IProcessStarting` event as then you'd have to set up the local registry (call `setSite`) on each and every Plone site before you can even access the registry utility.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've also realised that I need to handle the case where the settings in the registry change during runtime, then the menuItems will also need to change. Am I right in saying registrations like menuItems are per thread? in which case I'd somehow need to reinstall my menuItems on every thread. So I'm thinking the beforeSiteTraverse would need to look at a timestamp or hash from the db to work out if the menuItems are still valid. Is this going to perform? is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Sounds like you need to rethink this whole setup, and use a dynamic menu instead? In any case, component registrations are not per-thread, although they could be cached per thread perhaps. And a local component registry is persisted, and then the usual commit boundaries and per-thread object instance caches apply.